# Excel scroll not working in one worksheet after office upgrade to 365

Tags: excel, vba, scroll

I made a large automated workbook that my whole office uses for tracking samples into / out of our laboratory.  Recently, the office was upgraded to Office 365 and now mouse wheel scrolling seems to have stopped working in one sheet of the workbook for the whole office.

You can still navigate by clicking the up / down arrows on the scroll bar, ctrl + arrows, page up / down.  The only things affected are mouse wheel scrolling (which most people use) and middle click navigation.

The issue only seems to effect one sheet, but everyone in the office using 365 is affected.

Things I have checked:

- My code (there are no references to "scroll" anywhere)
- Freeze pane (panes frozen or not, there is no improvement)
- Setting ScrollArea for the affected sheet (ScrollArea = "" for all other sheets - no matter what I set the ScrollArea to, users cannot scroll)
- Scroll Lock is not activated (picture link to confirm: [Image of Scroll Lock off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL9vq.png))

Any insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated - whether I need to implement some new VBA, or it's just a setting alteration.

Comment: Does this happen to the sheet as well if you disallow VBA? What if you copy that sheet into a new workbook (that has no VBA code)? What if you extract that sheet into a new workbook? Maybe that's a solution and the issue is gone.

Comment: If I move the worksheet to a new workbook, the scroll issue moves with it.  There is no VBA code embedded on that worksheet specifically, and the new workbook has none - so it should not be an issue to do with the VBA.

Comment: Then it is technically off-topic because it is no programming question. The only quick idea I have to fix that is to copy the **content** of the sheet into a new one and see if that fixes the issue.